# Object window left over in a javascript bookmark

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarks

Currently I'm using the following as a bookmark in Firefox 3.6.3. It redirects me to the RFC just fine, but the active tab says [object Window]. What do I need to do to get rid of that artifact?

```
javascript:var rfc=prompt("RFC Number");window.open("http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc" + rfc + ".txt")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use also an auto-invoking anonymous function:

```
javascript:(function(){var rfc=prompt("RFC Number");window.open("http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc" + rfc + ".txt");})();
```

Since it doesn't have a return value, by default will return `undefined`, preventing the navigation.

It will work and your bookmarklet won't introduce any global variables on the page.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/void_Operator) to discard the return value.

```
javascript:void(window.open("http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc"+prompt("RFC Number")+".txt"));
```

Comment: I like that answer better than the function stuff above.
Though if you have more than one command you can't write them all within the brackets.
Solution is to just put the void at the end of all commands:
`javascript:var rfc=prompt("RFC Number");window.open("http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc" + rfc + ".txt");void(0);`